# Loop to copy text from two columns to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to copy name and last name from Excel, paste it into a Word template and print. I have an Excel file from which I need to copy two columns from each row (i.e. E31:F31,E40:F40) into a bookmark in Word and then print it.

1. I need to loop either from row X to Y or X number of times. The Excel file is not well formatted. I managed to apply paste&print to a custom number of cells, but I get an error probably because I try to do it all at once.

> document is in use do you want to open a temp copy

2. Copied text shows up in Word with big gaps between two words (what came from columns E and F). How do I fix?

```vb
Sub Copy_Excel_Cell_to_Word_Form()

    Dim wdApp As Object 'Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Object 'Word.Document
  
    For i = 31 To 60
  
        'Open new instance of Microsoft Word
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'Make application visible
        'wdApp.Visible = False
        'Open the word document
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("\\example.doc")
        'Copy value
        Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i, "F" & i).Copy
        'Paste to word document
        wdDoc.Bookmarks("WORKER").Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        wdDoc.PrintOut

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should use VBA to pull the data into a different Excel file (just the data you want, not all of it), clean it up as necessary, then use that file as a basis for Word's mail merge. What do you think of that?

Comment: You first point or question is confusing. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @Dick Yes you are right, I didn't know this tool. But on the other hand, I'm almost there with the VBA code :D.

Comment: @Seth Sure. I need to loop "copy,paste,print,go to next row and repeat' for eithes x number of loops or from row x to y instead of just doing all the matching ranges at once, which gives me "this document is locked" error

Answer (score 0):

For your second point, try this:

Declare a string variable called `workerName`. Instead of `Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i, "F" & i).Copy` use

```
workerName = Worksheets(1).Cells(i,5).Value 'e = 5
workerName = workerName & " " & Worksheets(1).Cells(i,6).Value & vbCr 'f = 6
```

And instead of use `wdDoc.Bookmarks("WORKER").Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)` use

```
wdDoc.Bookmarks("WORKER").Range.Text = workerName
```

This should clear up the big gaps.

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll have to check it back at the office, but looks good!